# RequireJS shim config doesn't recognize paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs, shim

So I am using requirejs in my project and I have a main folder with another folder in it. The main folder has the main.js and index.html in which there is a script tag with a data-main attribute pointing to the main.js. Inside the main.js, I have the require.config set up before proceeding with my require() call with all the dependencies. In the configuration, the baseUrl is set to "./". I want to reference a file inside the second folder using the shim config. However, when I try to do this, it gives the me the error that the file is not found. If I move the file that I want from the second folder into the main folder and then use the shim config it works perfectly fine. Only when I try to specify a path like so:

```
shim: {
"Other Files/fileIWant": {exports: 'whatever'}
}
```

it doesn't work. How can I use a path directory with the shim config?

Comment: Please include in your question your complete RequireJS configuration, the HTML you use to load and configure RequireJS, the exact `require` or `define` call that fails, and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Actually, when I include a "paths" property to the configuration and provide the path of the file that I want the shim for, then it works. My problem is the shin property (which is an object inside the configuration object) should be able to recognize paths itself without needing the "paths" property.

Comment: The `shim` you show *could* work, but this depends on what you do with the rest of your code, which you do not show in your question.